# I collected the coals to keep/kept me warm

Tags: infinitives

Which one is grammatically correct:

> I collected the coals to keep me warm

or

> I collected the coals to kept me warm

Comment: In the general construction ***do something** [in order] **to achieve something***, regardless of what *specific* verb is used to refer to the intended outcome *(**achieve, keep,...**)*, that verb is always an ***unmarked infinitive*** (the bare "root" form of the verb; note that ***to*** here is a preposition, not an "infinitive marker"). So you do something *[in order] to **keep** yourself warm*.

Comment: What if, I did something to keep me warm? or to kept me warm?

Comment: It is slightly ambiguous too – consider "I did some jobs to keep me warm" especially as we know what coal is used for.

Comment: So "to keep me warm" is right?

Comment: 'kept' is a past tense. "I carried out the ashes from the coal that had kept me warm." More nit-picking though: you collected coal for the fire: it is the fire that keeps you warm.

Comment: so what if was narrating a story from the past, so is it.. I collected the coals to keep me warm or to kept me warm?

Comment: "I collected the coals that would keep me warm", assuming they were for the fire, and not the exercise itself that was for warmth.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, "to" is not a preposition. Prepositions have noun objects. There's no noun object.

Comment: But you could say _I collected the coals (in summer) that kept me warm (all winter)_.

Comment: @gotube: Well, I'm no expert when it comes to "the naming of the parts". All I know is I'm quite happy to say ***to*** is an infinitive marker in ***I want to live***, but it looks like something completely different in ***I eat to live***, where ***to*** means ***in order to***. Maybe in that second context it still ***is*** an infinitive marker - but whatever it's called, it's obviously not the same as my first example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes as gotube mentioned it's not a preposition, not even in "I eat to live". Why? Notice that in all cases where preposition+verb form comes the verb is always in ing form. Neither in your sentence nor in OP's you can't use verb+ing after "to".

Comment: @Man_From_India: Perhaps I should never have mentioned the word "preposition" in the first place! The truth is I neither know nor care whether there's any formal grammatical ***terminology*** distinguishing the two different uses of "to" in *I eat to live* and *I want to live*. There are certainly "real-world" differences - not least of which can be seen in the huge *semantic* as well as syntactic difference if we introduce a secondary "object". (Compare *I want **you** to live* and *I eat **you** to live* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers your example sentence, just lol :D

Answer (score 2):

"I collected the coals to keep me warm" is correct. The other is incorrect.

In this context, "to" is a shortened form of the expression "in order to", which is always followed by a base form verb.

Comment: hi even i am narrating a story from the past? it is still "keep"

Comment: Yes. In this sentence, "keep" is the infinitive/base form, not the simple present. Only the verb "collected" needs to be in the simple past.